# Loading and Saving input and Output data into text files (Not Working)

Tags: java, user-interface, file-upload

I am trying to load my data for my program from a text file titled "inData.txt" and output it into the file "out.txt", basically imitating a Save. The problem is when I run this code through my GUI, it doesn't load to the text areas but saving it works. I don't know if it's a problem with my GUI code or the code in my League file itself.

I have tried checking if the text file changes and it doesn't but the code runs with no bugs.

```
//League.java

private static final String READ_FILE="inData.txt";
private static final String OUT_FILE="out.txt.";

public void readFromFile() //throwsIO exception /take from file into arraylist
{
    //reading the inData.txt file and loading the arraylist
    //with each instantiated object from the data
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(READ_FILE));
    //loop through the file and read each valie and create an object
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {

        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read name: " + name);

        String coach = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read coach: " + coach);

        int teamID = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("read team ID: " + teamID);

        int wins = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("read wins: " + wins);

        int losses = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read losses: " + losses);
        String player1 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 1 name: " + player1);
        String position1 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 1 position: " + position1);
        Player p1 = new Player(player1, position1);
        String player2 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 2 name: " + player2);
        String position2 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 2 position: " + position2);
        Player p2 = new Player(player2, position2);
        String player3 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 3: " + player3);
        String position3 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("read player 3 position: " + position3);
        Player p3 = new Player(player3, position3);

        //create and Item object
        Team newTeam = new Team(name, coach, teamID, wins, losses, p1, p2, p3);
        league.add(newTeam);
    }
        }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Error with file loading");
    }
}
```

The expected result from readFromFile() is to get the information from inData.txt and import it into the GUI.

Comment: If you're running a GUI, does that mean you don't get any console output? So how do you know that your code doesn't fail with an exception? And if it did, how would you know what that exception is when you discard it? Time for you to learn how to **debug** Java code.

Answer (score 0):

What do the contents of your file look like?

Given that you are looping by line, I'd recommend that you always use nextLine() and parse the String you get from that as needed. For example, if your file contents look like this:

```
line1
23:34:45:99
34
```

You could do:

```
if (in.hasNextLine()){
   String firstLine = in.nextLine();
   String secondLine = in.nextLine();
   int[] nums = new int[3];
   int i = 0;
   for (String intString : lineTwo.split(":")) {
      nums[i] = Integer.valueOf(intString);
      i++;
   }
   // or simply:
   int thirdLine = Integer.valueOf(in.next());
   // if you just have one int per line anyway
}
```

The problem that I am guessing you are running into involves slightly more advanced topics like codepoints or the difference between a newline and a carriage return, which you may be interested in learning about if you want to understand the intricacies of Scanner.

Let me know if this actually isn't the problem you're having and I'll edit my reply.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. To clarify. I am trying to input from a text file that includes:

`Flippy Frogs
Jackson
0
2.0
2.0 \n

Rockin Rocks
Jackson Michaels
1
3.0
1.0 \n

Lickin Lizards
Silvia Rock
2
0.0
0.0`

where it goes in order from (String) Team Name, (String) Team Coach, (int) Team ID, (double) Team Wins, and (double) Team Losses

Comment: Np, given what you're trying to do, what is the exact problem you are running into? Is it that you are writing only part of that content into the target file? Not reading from source or writing to target at all? Or something else? If the first, I'd still recommend the parse each nextLine() option (theres a Double.getValue(...) method too). If it's something else just let me know and I'll get back to you.

Comment: nextLine and nextInt are often not compatible because they terminate in different places in the input text, so if you are trying to do while(hasNextLine()), for example, I would not be surprised if your first Team object looked perfect, but then subsequent Team objects were not as expected and then an Exception was thrown before all Team objects were written to your output file.

Comment: Oh ok I think I got it down. These tips really helped me find an end solution. Thank you!